# Solving permutation problem

Tags: probability, permutations

I need to know the proper way to solve this kind of problem:Five employees of a firm are ranked from 1 to 5 based  on  their  ability  to  program  a  computer.Three  of  these  employees  are  selected  to  fill equivalent  programming  jobs.If all possible choices  of  three  (out  of  the  five)  are  equally likely,then how can we find the following probabilities:
    a)  The employee ranked number 1 is selected.
    b)  The  highest-ranked  employee  among  those
       selected has rank 2 or lower.
    c)  The employees ranked 4 and 5 are selected.

The correct answers are as follows: 6/10 or (36/60)  ,4/10, 3/5

I am aware of that the formula for probability is s/n;where n is the total number of outcomes.  I know how to get n by using $5_{P_3}$  (5 ways taking 3 at a time). Now, how do I get s (success outcome)? That confuses me. (I know that s(success outcome) is the number that will lock / target your condition) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line of thought is a little wrong.

You are choosing $3$ people out of $5$. This means, the order of choice doen't matter. More specifically, choosing $1$ then $2$ then $3$ is the same as $2$ then $1$ then $3$ and so on....

Therefore, the total number of ways of selecting $3$ people out of $5$, is the binomial coefficient $\binom{5}{3}=^5C_3$

The answer to (a) is, since the first guy is always chosen, you have a handle only on the choice of the other two. So, the number of possible ways of selecting $2$ people out $4$ is $^4C_2$

So, the probability is $\dfrac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{5}{2}}=\frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}$ which completes (a).

Along the same lines, (c) is also solved this way: You have handle only on one guy which means, you have to choose $1$ out of $3$ guys,  So, the probability is $\dfrac{\binom 3 1}{\binom 5 3}=\frac{3}{10}$

For (b), the condition imposed forbids you from choosing the candidate ranked (1). So, You need to choose $3$ out of $4$ people. So, the answer is $\dfrac{\binom 4 3}{\binom 5 3}=\frac{4}{10}=\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: but, shouldn't we use permutations here? coz ranking is invovled (like in the first sentence) ? tnx

Comment: No, did you read my explanation? The point is , three people  are chosen; it is like this: choosing $123$ is no different from choosing $231$ and so on...

Comment: ok. its 5C3, but how do we get "s" (success outcomes)

Comment: how do we get 6 mathematically? i cant figure out / find how to lock down the target

Comment: thanks! i guess i was thinking too much. you made my day